# Can a class containing a container of unique pointers as member only be stored in the same type of container?

Tags: c++, containers, unique-ptr

In a project of mine I use a container to store unique pointers. Initially I used `std::vector` as container, but after some redesigning I decided that `std::list` would be a better fit.
So, my initial code was:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class vec
{
public:
    int ID = -1;
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> vec_container;

    vec() = default;
    vec(int ID) : ID(ID) {}
};



int main()
{
    std::vector<vec> vec_s;

    vec_s.emplace_back(vec(1));
    vec_s.emplace_back(vec(2));
    vec_s.emplace_back(vec(3));

    for (auto& v : vec_s)
        std::cout << v.ID << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

After changing the container my code was:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <memory>

class list
{
public:
    int ID = -1;
    std::list<std::unique_ptr<int>> list_container;

    list() = default;
    list(int ID) : ID(ID) {}
};


int main()
{
    std::vector<list> list_s;

    list_s.emplace_back(list(1));
    list_s.emplace_back(list(2));
    list_s.emplace_back(list(3));

    for (auto& l : list_s)
        std::cout << l.ID << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

But after I changed `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> vec_container` to `std::list<std::unique_ptr<int>> list_container`. I got an error that told me that I copied an unique pointer. This confused me and I wondered if it happenend due to the nature of `std::list`, but I found nothing indicating something like that.

So, after some fiddeling I discovered that if I changed `std::vector<list> list_s`, to `std::list<list> list_s` the error vanished, the code compiled and worked properly.

Does this mean that a class containing a container of unique pointers as member can only be stored in the same type of container? Or is there something very simple I am missing?

PS: I use Visual Studio 2019's latest compiler.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://godbolt.org/z/awESWX. Please provide a better [mcve] if possible and more details about the compiler you are using

Comment: The shown code in this question fails to meet stackoverflow.com's requirements for a [mre], and because of that it is unlikely that anyone on stackoverflow.com can determine the problem. This question must be [edit]ed to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that anyone can cut/paste, compile, run, and reproduce the described problem (the "reproducible" part) ***exactly as shown*** (this includes any ancillary information, like the input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: I too, can't reproduce your error. Just a small note, that `As.emplace_back(A());` is redundant. It will construct an instance of `A` then, move-construct an element in `As`. You can simply use `As.emplace_back()`, this will invoke the default constructor `A()`.

Comment: I edited my question and reproduced the error: https://godbolt.org/z/NWFAEQ.

Comment: I think you've encountered a bug in MSVC or their standard library implementation since your code seems to compile just fine with GCC and Clang. I've managed to compile it with MSVC by adding an explicitly-defaulted move constructor `list(list &&) = default` but I'm not sure yet why does this fix the problem and where is the problem in the first place.